# Hidden AdornedElementPlaceholder in validationTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf

Dear honorable people of stackoverflow, why is my textbox, which is my validated control, hidden behind the DockPanel Background in this template?

```
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="validationTemplate">
        <DockPanel Background="Black">
            <TextBlock Foreground="Red" FontSize="20">!</TextBlock>
            <AdornedElementPlaceholder/>
        </DockPanel>
    </ControlTemplate>
```

If the Background is set to "Transparent" the Textbox is visible but i´m not able to click inside (cursor won´t change).

How can i set a Background for my template without hiding my AdorendElementPlaceholder?

thanks gpx

Comment: +1 had the exact same problem a couple of weeks ago, gave up searching. For some reason the background swallows the cursor before it gets to the texbox. I tried fiddling with z-axis settings etc but couldn't find a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The adorner layer does sit on top of the element, and can intercept mouse interactions. In your case, by applying a background to the DockPanel, you're indicating to WPF that the object has area that is "HitTestVisible" and will intercept mouse clicks.

Another confusing note is that "Transparent" is still HitTestVisible. If you don't want it to intercept mouse clicks, then you should set the background to "{x:Null}" or leave it blank.

Two options:

1. Set the **Background="{x:Null}"**. This is basically no background and prevent mouse hit tests.
2. Specify **IsHitTestVisible="False"** on the DockPanel. This will allow mouse interactions to bypass that layer and go to the next available layer.

**EDIT:**

Here's an example that works for me in KaXaml. Just type something like "word" in the textboxes to generate a validation error. By setting the background color to a semi-transparent color, I'm able to see the textbox. Setting IsHitTestVisible="False" allows me to click into the textbox with my mouse.

```
<Page
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
  <Page.Resources>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="validationTemplate">
        <DockPanel Background="#5000" IsHitTestVisible="False">
            <TextBlock Foreground="Red" FontSize="20">!</TextBlock>
            <AdornedElementPlaceholder/>
        </DockPanel>
    </ControlTemplate>
    <Style TargetType="TextBox" x:Key="validationStyle">
      <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="True">
          <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green" />
        </Trigger>
      </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
  </Page.Resources>
  <StackPanel Name="grd" Width="100" Height="100">  
    <TextBox 
        VerticalAlignment="Top"
        Validation.ErrorTemplate="{StaticResource validationTemplate}"
        Text="{Binding ElementName=grd, Path=Width, Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnExceptions=True}" />
    <TextBox 
        VerticalAlignment="Top"
        Text="{Binding ElementName=grd, Path=Height, Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnExceptions=True}"
        Style="{StaticResource validationStyle}"
        >
    </TextBox>
  </StackPanel>
</Page>
```

Comment: I tried with IsHitTestVisible="False", doesn't work. The option of setting Background to null is not really an option, as the author wants a colooured background.

Comment: I edited my answer to include an example that works for me in KaXaml. This uses the approach in your template. I would note, however, that if your main goal is to get the background of the textbox to change color, you can do this more easily by setting up a style on the textbox that reacts to the "Validation.HasError" attached property. Then you can style the text box as you wish. I'll add a sample of that too.

Comment: sorry, my mistake, I was trying it on a TextBox that had it's IsEnabled set to false. IsHitTestVisible="False" does work.

Comment: Thanks for you help NathanAW, works fine for me with HitTest.